# ORDS FILE UPLOAD NON-APEX MOD_PLSQL APPLICATION

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords, mod-plsql

We are in the process of upgrading a mod_plsql application to ORDS 3.  I found some information under:  File uploads in a non-Apex PL/SQL application migrated to ORDS.  In this, Kris Rice states, "Important question. Do you have apex in this db at all? my answer is different based on that."  Then an Answer is provided.  I am unable to tell if this Answer was for having apex in the DB or not having Apex in the DB.  We do not have Apex in the DB.  I've tried the steps in the Answer but we get:  PLS-00306:wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPLOAD_PROC'.

Has anyone been able to get file upload to work without much code changes when moving a mod_plsql application to ORDS3?

Answer (score 0):

This is the current logic.

This SQL is executed in the schema.

```
select  version_no from apex_release
```

***If*** that is 4+ Then this is run

```
begin ? := apex_util.set_blob(.... ); end;";
```

***If*** is less than 4, Then this is run where %s is the value of `apex.docTable` in the defaults.xml

```
BEGIN INSERT INTO %s (name, mime_type, content_type, dad_charset, last_updated, blob_content)
```

Comment: I've created the view apex_release, verified my url-mapping.xml, and added an entry similar to <entry key="apex.docTable">klrice.MYDOCTABLE</entry>
to conf/<name>.xml but I'm getting this error:  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPLOAD_PROC'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: can you drop me an email and we can do a webshare/webex/... and see what's up?

Comment: My table has more than 6 columns:     NAME          VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  MIME_TYPE     VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  DOC_SIZE      NUMBER,
  DAD_CHARSET   VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
  LAST_UPDATED  DATE                            NOT NULL,
  CONTENT_TYPE  VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  OT_FORMAT     VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)                DEFAULT 'BINARY'              NOT NULL,
  BLOB_CONTENT  BLOB                            NOT NULL

Comment: That should be fine. The ones listed above are the minimum needed. Are all of those present ?

Comment: They should be.  I'm trying to get the app working.  I didn't write the code.  The developers are asking that apex be installed.  They are concerned with the apex references in the Stack Trace:  InternalServerException [statusCode=500, reasons=[]]
 at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApexContext.handleError(ModApexContext.java:273)
 at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:222)
 at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.handleRequest(ModApex.java:266)
 at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.doPost(ModApex.java:174)
 at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.service(ModApex.java:102)

Comment: naw that's not apex. That's the java code that does all OWA stuff apex or not.  With that said migrating to apex over straight htp.p is nice.

Comment: I feel I am so close, I wanted to get this working before I install apex.  If we install apex.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow.  Kris Rice mentioned that I could send him an email.  How do I find his email?

Comment: I've reviewed all of my parameters and still can't find what is wrong.  Still can't get File Upload to work.  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPLOAD_PROC' ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the steps indicated by Kris Rice, we had CONTENT_TYPE VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) NOT NULL in our upload table.  We changed this to allow nulls and our file upload started working.

Comment: Guess I spoke too soon.  Should our upload procedure have to be modified?  Not only is the CONTENT_TYPE not being passed neither are DOC_SIZE nor DAD_CHARSET.  I know we can add a before_insert trigger to handle this but should that be necessary?